# KeyEvent never fires (java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

at this moment I'm trying to add to my project Keyboard support and i have wird problem. My listener doesn't catch any events. I did simple prints in code but nothing happends. I've never had such problem before.

This is my class GUI:

```
public class GUI extends JPanel {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ComponentAbstract korzen;
private GUI self;
public GUI() {

    self=this;

    this.stworz_PanelLogowania();



    this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("typed");    
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("pressed");

        }
    });


this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseClicked(e);
        korzen.tryClick(e.getX(), e.getY());
        repaint();
    }
});

 this.repaint();

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g ) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    korzen.repaint();
    System.out.println("omatko");
    korzen.draw((Graphics2D)g);

}

private void zmien_panel(ComponentAbstract newkorzen){
    korzen=newkorzen;
    self.repaint();
}


private void stworz_PanelLogowania(){


    LinearPanel lp=new LinearPanel(220, 50, 300, 300);
    //lp.setOrientarion(Orientation.VERTICAL);

    lp.addComponent(new Label(0, 0, 350, 40, "Witamy w castorama APP"));
    lp.setPadding(2);
    lp.addComponent(new TextBox(0, 0, 350, 40));
    korzen=lp;
    System.out.println("kuniec");
}


}
```

What is interesting Mouse listener works perfect.
Edit: Before there was KeyAdapter but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component with focus. By default a JPanel is not focusable, so it will not receive KeyEvents.

In the constructor you need to use:

```
setFocusable(true);
```

Then depending on the rest of your application the panel can now receive focus when you tab to the panel.